# How to get Entity Framework to create a "char" from an enum

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, types, dbcontext

I'm working on a C# application, based on Entity Framework.
In order to create the database, this is what I do:

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
context.Database.Migrate();
```

, where `context` is an object, inherited from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`.

One of my objects, has an attribute `Type` from the following type:

```
public enum ObjectType
{
    After='A',
    Before='B'
}
```

I would expect the Entity Framework to generate the SQL-Server database with that attribute being a char, but instead, it's an integer, containing the ASCII code of that char (65 and 66, which is not very readable):
My SQL-Server session gives me the following result (I'm sure I'm referring to the correct object):

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Type%'
```

Result:

```
DATA_TYPE
int
```

I would like Entity Framework to generate my database with that column being of the type `char`.

How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the meantime, I've seen that my question is in fact a duplicate and hence, it can be closed.

Comment: There are no character enums. Enums are labels for integers. Your enum's values aren't characters, they're the integer values of those characterters, 65 and 66. Check what the compiler generates [in this Sharplab example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAICmA7ArgW3QHkAjAK0wGMAXAFQE8AHTZAb2XU/QEEAzazACcAvAHJuogDQcuAIUy8A9oMxjZo5AF9kadLHQBhdOyRc9GKABZ0AWQAUASmMzO2pJqA=)

Comment: Why are you trying to use characters as enum values in the first place?